# kernel.yama.protected_nonaccess_hardlinks is an unknown key

Tags: kernel, snapshot

I want to clear the snapshots of Cassandra using :

```
nodetool -h localhost -p 7199 clearsnapshot
```

but it gives me an exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" FSWriteError in /var/lib/cassandra/data/system   /compactions_in_progress/snapshots/1423043461812-compactions_in_progress/system-compactions_in_progress-jb-2097-Statistics.db
```

to solve this issue i ran this command :

```
sudo  sysctl -w kernel.yama.protected_nonaccess_hardlinks=0
```

but it gives me `kernel.yama.protected_nonaccess_hardlinks is an unknown key`

so what is the problem and how can i solve it ?

Comment: in my case it resolved by rebooting

Answer (score 0):

While you already solved your issue by rebooting, I'm posting in hopes that someone else will benefit. I know I would have.

It seems that the sysctl was changed somewhere between the kernels used in Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04. The new sysctl key is `fs.protected_hardlinks`. There is also a config for this (and the similar key `fs.protected_symlinks`) in `/etc/sysctl.d/10-link-restrictions.conf` that will enable this by default at boot, so be sure to edit this file as well.